# How to add a form name to a form in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I add a form name to the following line?

```
<% form_tag({}, :method => :get) do %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<% form_tag({}, :method => :get, :name => "whatever") do %>
```